# Are Nix expressions without any logic on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I've written a configuration.nix file for my systems, and it would be very useful to have it reviewed. **Nix expressions are code,** very similarly to Puppet or Chef, but are declarative, so I wonder if it's on topic.

Comment: For those unaware: Nix is the configuration language (and package manager) for nixOS.